# Wait until ajax request has been completed

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is a javascript function:

```
  function getValue(key) {
    var value;
    switch(_options.myType){
      case "cookie":
        value = readFromCookie(key);
        break;
      case "localStorage":
        value = readFromLocalStorage(key);
        break;
      case "db":
        //return value from the server
        // how do I wait for the result?
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "123",
            data: { .... },
            success: function(data){
               value = data; 
            }
        });
        break;
    }
    return value;
  };
```

In case of sending ajax request, I need to wait untill the ajax request has been completed. How can I do it?

Not that I **can't** leave the function without having the value calculated. Which means that I can't place a function inside `success:` handler which will return the value later (or perhaps I don't understand something?). So it must be calculated within the function `getValue()`.

**UPDATE**

**P.S.** So how do refactor my code to be able to use callback inside `success:` handler? Here is the second part of the code:

```
MyClass123.prototype.myMethod = function(value) {
      //..............
      var var1 = this.getValue("key1");
      if (var1 == "123") { ... }
      else { .... }
      //..............
    }
  };
```

Comment: It's impossible. Do you know what the word "asynchronous" in "asynchronous javascript and xml" means? It means you _can't wait_

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Comment: If you don't need to return anything from `myMethod`, it's easy. If you do, you need to refactor the code that _uses_ `myMethod`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**See follow-up below**

You *could* make the ajax request synchronous, but that's generally a bad idea (and jQuery won't support it much longer).

Instead, make `getValue` accept a callback:

```
function getValue(key, callback) {
   switch(_options.myType){
     case "cookie":
       setTimeout(function() {
           callback(readFromCookie(key));
       }, 0);
       break;
     case "localStorage":
       setTimeout(function() {
           callback(readFromLocalStorage(key));
       }, 0);
       break;
     case "db":
       //return value from the server
       // how do I wait for the result?
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "123",
           data: { .... },
           success: function(data){
              callback(data);
           }
       });
       break;
   }
}
```

Note that I'm using `setTimeout` for the `readFromCookie` and `readFromLocalStorage` callbacks. Why? Because if `getValue` *might* return its value asynchronously, it should *always* do so. using a timeout of `0` asks the browser to do it as soon as possible once control yields back to the browser (although it's usually clamped to no less than 5-10ms).

---

Re your comment below:

> Have you read what I write? I said that I can't do it for some reason.

I missed that bit, but with all due respect, you **can**. It may require some refactoring of code, but you *can* do it, and should. This is how modern web applications work. If your structure doesn't support it, you need to fix the structure. You can use [`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) on the request as a **temporary** workaround until you can do it properly. (Hey, we've all been there and had to do things like that.) Note that it's scheduled for retirement before too long (just jQuery's support of it, you'll still be able to use XHR directly to do synchronous requests).

---

Re your updated question, here's how you update that code:

```
MyClass123.prototype.myMethod = function(value) {
  this.getState("key1", function(var1) {
    //                           ^--- Note the var becomes an arg
    if var1 == "123"{ ... }
    else { .... }
  });
};
```

Note how little it actually changes. The logic that used to *follow* the call to `getState` instead goes into the callback you pass into it.

Comment: Have you read what I write? I said that I can't do it for some reason.

Comment: @AlanDert: I missed that bit, but with all due respect, you **can**. It may require some refactoring of code, but you *can* do it, and should. This is how modern web applications work. If your structure doesn't support it, you need to fix the structure. (You can use [`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) on the request as a **temporary** workaround until you can do it properly.)

Comment: +2 for "temporary workaround". It's nothing more than a kludge.

Comment: @AlanDert: I've updated the answer to show how to modify that code.

Comment: Thanks. Should I not change the code of getValue(key) at all then?

Comment: @AlanDert: Yes, you'd change it as shown in the main part of the answer. (The two code snippets go together.) Have to dash, hope this helps,

Comment: as @techfoobar said, it would be helpful to use 'when' and 'then', would not it? So there will be no need to use a callback function.

Comment: @AlanDert - The function you pass to `then` is the same as having a callback. So there is no real difference. You're still doing the rest in a callback with when and then.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the AJAX request synchronous by specifying `async: false` - ***which is not recommended but possible.*** If it absolutely is the case that your `getValue()` function should not return before the AJAX request returns, then `async` is the way to go.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "123",
    async: false // NEW
    data: { .... },
    success: function(data){
        value = data; 
    }
});
```

---

Alternative using `then` and `when`:

```
function getValue(key, callback) {
   switch(_options.myType){

     ...

     case "db":
       return $.ajax({ // note the 'return'
           type: "GET",
           url: "123",
           ...
       });
   }
}
```

and where you call it, call it like:

```
$.when(getValue()).then(function() {
   // do the rest here ...
});
```

Comment: Note that `async` is deprecated

Comment: Just noted that. Tks. Guess they haven't introduced an alternative that does exactly what `async: false` does. But then, properly structured apps shouldn't ever need `async: false`

Comment: what should I use instead of ajax async false then to make it work the same way?

Comment: Thanks. Is using 'when' and 'then' make execute the code asynchronously?

Comment: It doesn't make it synchronous. The *waiting and triggering the callback* bit will be handled internally. Thats all.

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do is to restructure your program flow so you *can* place your logic in the `success` handler.

You can make Ajax requests synchronous by using the `async` option, but that is silly. It'll slow down your app, because the browser window freezes until the request comes back successful (or times out). It's not often used in JavaScript development and for good reason.

Comment: Note that `async` is deprecated